# Navit embedded in Qt Canvas

Tags: qt, qt4, navigation, hook

I would like to embed navit into my custom car gauge dashbaord.  My application right now gathers data on my car's current state (speed, rpm, etc.) and displays it on the screen.  I would like to embedded navit in the middle of the gauges so that I can have navigation right in the dashboard.  Is there anyway to embed another application into a drawing canvas that something like QPainter draws too, if not is there a way I can pull this off using a grid something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The Navit wiki has a short page on how to [Embed navit in your own application](http://wiki.navit-project.org/index.php/Embed_navit_in_your_own_application).

Comment: I saw that.  Not sure how I can draw navit's map to a qpainter style canvas.